# Extracting emails from excel string

Tags: excel, ms-office

So I found few forumlas online to do this but every single time I get this error:

```
http://postimg.org/image/4flyu43kp/
```

I have no idea whats going on. Im using office professional plus 2013. Here is an example how emails are placed in strings

```
name / something <info@example1.com>
<info@example2.com>
```

All emails are in brackets BTW < >
I need to extract just the email, can someone plz help me?

Comment: What formula are you using? Also, you can post the image directly in your question.

Comment: I tried also this one Gary posted but same result... I have no idea why am i getting this error message all the time...

Answer (score 1):

With a string in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE((MID(A1,FIND("<",A1,1)+1,9999)),">","")
```

**EDIT:**

So if **A1** contains:

```
something<bionicle.bill@lego.com>
```

**B1** will display:

```
bionicle.bill@lego.com
```

Comment: Thx for youre replay, but i again get the same error message... I have no idea what im doing wrong

Comment: Start with a clean worksheet......put my sample in **A1** and my formula in **B1**...........what do you see?????

Comment: I tried that but i get same error... What could be cousing this? Is my office messed up? Or some functions configuration is wrong...